# C programming questions from a java programmer

Tags: c, memory, pointers, allocation

So I'm in the need to translate a C library to pure java, so far its looking good, but I'm stuck here.

Can someone explain to me what does the following pointer is for?

```
double *DTimeSigBuf[MAX_TIME_CHANNELS];
```

Ok I know it is a double type pointer named DTimeSigBuf, but whats that in the brackets? also MAX_TIME_CHANNELS is defined in the h file as:

```
 #define MAX_TIME_CHANNELS 2
```

then in the code this constant value changes, like its pointing somewhere else, but I dont know what does exactly means. is it equivalent to say:

```
double *DTimeSigBuf = MAX_TIME_CHANNELS;
```

if I recall well there was something similar in assembler, like: `mov [BX], CL` called Indirect addressing mode register, does this have anything to do with this? I know I might be completly lost! because as the title says, I'm a java programmer.

And the other question, what is the effect of doing this:

```
DTimeSigBuf[chanNum]            = (double*)malloc(block_size_samples*sizeof(double));
```

Where block_size_samples is int and chanNum is an for iterator variable?

Please help! I sware I've been googling the whole time.

Thanks folks :)

Comment: Doesn't Java also have brackets? They serve a similar purpose in C.

Comment: the questions are basic enough that instead of asking individual questions that you should look at a tutorial first - especially looking at arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DTimeSigBuf` is an array of pointers to type `double`. This could be thought of as an array of arrays of type `double`.

```
double *DTimeSigBuf[MAX_TIME_CHANNELS];
```

could be thought of as

```
double DTimeSigBuf[MAX_TIME_CHANNELS][]
```

The line

```
DTimeSigBuf[chanNum] = (double*)malloc(block_size_samples*sizeof(double));
```

is allocating memory for `block_size_samples` number of variables of type `double` to be placed in the array pointed at by `DTimeSigBuf[chanNum]`.

**For example:**

If `block_size_samples` is `4` and `chanNum` is `1`, you could think of it this way:

```
DTimeSigBuf[1] = new double[4];
```

Comment: Nit: it's an array of pointer to `double`, not a pointer to an array of `double`.

Answer (score 5):

It is an array of pointers to double. MAX_TIME_CHANNELS is size of the array.

The effect of the statement with malloc is allocation of a block of memory large enough for block_size_samples double values; address of the block of memory is then assigned to chanNum element of the DTimeSigBuf array.

Comment: By the way #define MAX_TIME_CHANNELS 2, will cause that the precompiler will replace with 2 every ocurrece of MAX_TIME_CHANNELS, so the declaration will be compiles as double *DTimeSigBuf[2];

Answer (score 3):

Its an array pointer of type double. MAX_CHANNEL_TIMES is a constant and also the array size

Answer (score 3):

If you have C code like:

```
#define MAX_TIME_CHANNELS 2 
double *DTimeSigBuf[MAX_TIME_CHANNELS];
```

In Java it looks like:

```
final static int MAX_TIME_CHANNELS = 2;
double DTimeSigBuf[][] = new double[MAX_TIME_CHANNELS][];
```

And this in C:

```
DTimeSigBuf[chanNum] = (double*)malloc(block_size_samples*sizeof(double));
```

is allocating space for the y dimension.

In Java it is:

```
DTimeSigBuf[chanNum] = new double[block_size_samples];
```

Answer (score 2):

`DTimeSigBuf` is an array of pointers to doubles.

The allocation is allocating an array of doubles.  That is, the pointer that's returned is a pointer to the first double in an array of `block_size_samples` doubles.

Answer (score 1):

As previously answered, the first sections are declaring an array of pointers to doubles. Since declaration does not *necessarily* allocate memory in C, the third line is allocating space for a new row of doubles.

Breaking it down:

```
DTimeSigBuf[chanNum] // chanNum is the position in the array
= // equals
(double*) // memory address to a double
malloc(  // get some memory from the system
block_size_samples*sizeof(double)); // number of samples times memory needed for one double
```